# How to Filter facebook friends by age using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I want to filter friends of the current user by their age. Is this possible using FQL? If so, what would the query look like?

-- EDIT --

An example of the kind of filtering im looking at is:

Find all friends between the age of 20-30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will list your friends along with their birthdays. You can simply modify it to display pages fans:

```
fql?q=SELECT uid, birthday_date FROM user where uid IN (select uid2 from friend WHERE uid1=me() ) order by birthday_date DESC
```

Comment: But can I perform filtering like say, only friends who are 18-30 years old?

Answer (score 0):

First calculate the years in whatever language you're using e.g. in JavaScript (see below), and then get the year out of the birthday_date field using substr() and compare them. Note that access to the birthday_date field requires the friends_birthday permission.

```
var year = new Date().getFullYear();
var twentyYearsAgo = year - 20,
  thirtyYearsAgo = year - 30;

var query = "SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND substr(birthday_date,6,10) > " + thirtyYearsAgo + " AND substr(birthday_date,6,10) < " + twentyYearsAgo";
```